# mapping more than 2 table in hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, hibernate-mapping

i have three table and i want to map them in hibernate 4.
i am using many to one annotation. i don't know how to map more than 2 table.

```
1. Stuff
CREATE  TABLE TBLSTUFF (
  STUFF_ID                         NUMBER NOT NULL,
  STUFF_DESCRIPTION                VARCHAR2(10),
  MUNIT                            VARCHAR2(10),
  ORDERPOINT                       NUMBER,
  STOCK                            NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBLSTUFF
    PRIMARY KEY ( STUFF_ID ) 
);
2. STUFFRECEPTION
CREATE  TABLE TBLSTUFFRECEPTION (
  STUFF_ID                         NUMBER,
  PROVIDER_ID                      NUMBER,
  RECEPTIONDATE                    DATE,
  QUANTITY                         NUMBER,
  RECEPTION_ID                     NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBLSTUFFRECEPTION
    PRIMARY KEY ( RECEPTION_ID ) 
);


ALTER TABLE TBLSTUFFRECEPTION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_STUFF
  FOREIGN KEY (STUFF_ID)
    REFERENCES TBLSTUFF (STUFF_ID);

ALTER TABLE TBLSTUFFRECEPTION ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PROVIDER
  FOREIGN KEY (PROVIDER_ID)
    REFERENCES TBLPROVIDER (PROVIDER_ID);


3.provider
CREATE  TABLE TBLPROVIDER (
  PROVIDER_ID                      NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PROVIDER_NAME                    VARCHAR2(10),
  PROVIDER_ADDRESS                 VARCHAR2(10),
  PROVIDER_TELL                    VARCHAR2(11),
  CONSTRAINT PK_TBLPROVIDER
    PRIMARY KEY ( PROVIDER_ID ) 
);
```

in Stuffreception.java, how should write the many to one annotation?
is this true?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBLSTUFFRECEPTION")
public class Stuffreception {
@Id
@Column(name="RECEPTION_ID")
private int recep_id;
@Column(name="QUANTITY")
private int quantity;
@Column(name="RECEPTIONDATE")
private Date recep_date;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PROVIDER_ID")
private Provider provider;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="STUFF_ID")
private Stuff stuff;

public Stuffreception(int recep_id, int quantity, Date recep_date) {
    super();
    this.recep_id = recep_id;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.recep_date = recep_date;
}
//getter and setter method
```

please help me.

Comment: are you facing any errors? This seems OK.

Comment: @BharatSinha, i have no error, i just know it is true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how I have done it in my application. So this is the way to go.